# Fix iOS viewport in place to prevent 'drag' effect

Tags: jquery, ios, css

Is there a way to 'fix' the browser viewport in place in iOS (iPhone and iPad) to prevent the background movement on swipe?  The screen will fit the 1024x768 landscape/portrait dimenions so doesnt need to scroll at all..

I need to build a training site that replies on swipe actions to trigger functions - but the moving screen makes this effect look awful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to capture and prevent the `ontouchmove` event for the whole document.

HTML:

```
<body ontouchmove="BlockElasticScroll(event);">
    <!-- CONTENT -->
</body>
```

JS:

```
function BlockElasticScroll(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Instead of binding to the native JS, you easily re-write this to jQuery using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("body").on({
    ontouchmove : function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

(jQuery code is not tested).

I have to say this approach isn't rock-solid the last time I checked, because "sometimes" the scrolling does take place.

You can also take a look at **[ScrollFix](https://github.com/joelambert/ScrollFix)** to create fullscreen web apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your container/wrapper div(s) (or perhaps even the body, I haven't tested it) to `max-width: 100%;` it seems to alleviate this problem.